# fuse overlapping elements with transparent background and box shadow

Tags: html, canvas, css, rgba

I'm trying to make two elements line up and fuse -- as if they were one element -- normally I would overlap them a bit and they will pretty readily look like one element but the elements I am using both have a partially transparent background so the overlap looks funny -- it'll be darker than the rest of the backgrounds and you'll see the box shadow very clearly

http://jsfiddle.net/vbh4u/7/

I have tried lining my elements up perfectly but then you still see the bit of shadow showing up--i also played with a negative number for the spread value on the box shadow but this isn't ideal because i only need part of the element to not have a shadow, as in half of one side, not all of one side...

I've been looking around a bit and I can't find anything, anyone have ideas?

*EDIT:*

I know very little about the canvas element, but would there be a way to use canvas to do something like this, as in draw a complex shape on the cavas and lay that beneath the content?

Comment: Put `.main` div into a div with `overflow: hidden` can hide `.main` div bottom shadow. However, I'm afraid that it's impossible to hide top shadow (part which intersect with `.main` div) of `.bottom` div

Comment: that was sort of my hypothesis, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's my try: http://jsfiddle.net/Simo990/YxRWp/4/

Just removed negative margin and top shadow. It's not properly what you want, but... hope you like it.

Comment: this is pretty close except that i'd need the .bottom element to also have a top box shadow--but only on either side of .main -- thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vbh4u/9/